# PostgreSQL for each row from one table join all rows from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, left-join

In table `A` I have dates from `2014-01-01` to `2014-12-31`

```
 action_date
 2014-01-01
 2014-01-02
 2014-01-03
 ...
 2014-12-31
```

In table `B` I have some information like

```
id name action_date deletion_date
1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
3  lola 2013-12-30  2014-01-01
```

I want to join row from B table to each `A` table row if `activation_date<=action_date<=deletion_date`

e.g.

```
 action_date id name action_date deletion_date
 2014-01-01  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
 2014-01-01  3  lola 2013-12-30  2014-01-01
 2014-01-02  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
 2014-01-03  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03
   [...]
 2014-02-03  1  nik  2013-01-01  2014-02-03

 2014-06-02  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
 2014-06-03  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
   [...]
 2014-06-03  2  tom  2014-06-02  2014-06-30
```

I tried to use left join without on statement, only with where condition. Unfortunately, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `between` operator in your `join` condition:

```
SELECT a.action_date, b.*
FROM   b
JOIN   a ON a.action_date BETWEEN b.activation_date AND b.deletion_date
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I have one more question. How should I do, if I   need to add one more condition on deletion_date:
action_date>= activation_date AND (action_date<=deletion_date OR deletion_date='1970-01-01'

Comment: @Marta Just like you wrote it :-) Replace my `on` condition with yours, and you should be fine.